# How to inspect hidden GET/POST request Flash & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, flash, curl

I tested one website and find flash object with buttons in it. When I clicked on that buttons and inspect in firebug -> Networks, I see next request:

GET http://website.com/element.php?id=2

I copied that request and put it in firefox address bar and send request, but nothing to happen.
I tried copy request from firebug as curl with all headers, params, cookies and send from command line, also tried send from POSTMAN with same parameters and headers. I can't understand how it possible that when I click button in flash anything is good but when I send like request no any changes on the page.

Comment: Possibly you are doing something wrong. It will be easier for me to help you, if you can put your curl's commandline here.

Comment: curl 'http://www.example.com/move_sector.php?id=1&rand=0.863' -H 'Host: www.example.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Referer: http://www.example.com/map.php' -H 'Cookie: cookies here' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'

Comment: Hopefully you are using this from windows, and it doesn't support single `quote(')`. Change all those into double `quote(")`. Also, you do not need to use `semi-colon(;)` after the url. Finally, you do not need to provide the `Connection` and `Host` Header with curl.

Comment: I use ubuntu there doesn't matter quote ' or ". I took into account all the above, but no any changes, flash object doesn't receive any actions. In any case thank you for answer.